# linkage error with non-member functions

Tags: static, namespaces

```
------------------blah.h------------------------
#pragma once
namespace SomeNamespace{
 static void someMethod(){}
}
-----------------blah.c--------------------------
#include “blah.h”
int main(int argc, char**argv){
 SomeNamespace::someMethod();
return 0;
}
```

The above works fine but if I omit ‘static’ I get:

```
>stdafx.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl SomeNamespace::someMethod(void)"
(?someMethod@SomeNamespace@@YAXXZ) already defined in Dude.obj
1>...\Debug\Dude.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined
symbols found
```

I read about what ‘static’ does to non-member functions – 
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t284052-static-functions.html
…

> ...give it internal linkage so that it won't be visible outside the compilation unit -- i.e., (over-simplified) the linker will not see it.
>   This use of 'static' is deprecated, and imposes the limitation that the function cannot be used as a template argument.
>   The modern way is to instead place the function in an anonymous namespace…

But the thing is I want the method to be exposed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

- **Declare** your function in .h  (i.e. `void foo(int x);`)
- **Define** then in .c (i.e. `void foo(int x) { ... }`)